# How to create a fixed size (unsigned) integer in python?

Tags: python, int, fixed-size-types

I want to create a fixed size integer in python, for example 4 bytes. Coming from a C background, I expected that all the primitive types will occupy a constant space in memory, however when I try the following in python:

```
import sys  
print sys.getsizeof(1000)
print sys.getsizeof(100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

I get

```
>>>24  
>>>52
```

respectively.
How can I create a fixed size (unsigned) integer of 4 bytes in python? I need it to be 4 bytes regardless if the binary representation uses 3 or 23 bits, since later on I will have to do byte level memory manipulation with Assembly.

Comment: Then i think you are using the wrong language for that. If you have to do something in Assembly to optimize speed/memory you should stick with C and not use a semi-interpreted language like python

Comment: If you are going to do low-level calls to Assembly, start reading up on the ctypes module.

Comment: I agree with saftco.  If you really need to do it in python, maybe pass it through a C function before you try to manipulate it with assembly.

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha Actually there are plenty of tools in Python to accomodate this kind of thing. It's very much designed to be a "glue" language for lower-level languages. Although Adam Miller has the right idea — going through C might be a better idea.

Comment: This is a program for the BeagleBoneBlack and all the packages are in python. Therefore _generally_ is easier to stick in python. However, cannot avoid Assembly, because we will have to use the PRU units. Ctypes could be a viable option. I will test it out along with struct.pack, as Simeon Visser suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way I do this (and its usually to ensure a fixed width integer before sending to some hardware) is via ctypes

```
from ctypes import c_ushort 

def hex16(self, data):
    '''16bit int->hex converter'''
    return  '0x%004x' % (c_ushort(data).value)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
def int16(self, data):
    '''16bit hex->int converter'''
    return c_ushort(int(data,16)).value
```

otherwise struct can do it

```
from struct import pack, unpack
pack_type = {'signed':'>h','unsigned':'>H',}
pack(self.pack_type[sign_type], data)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) with the `I` modifier (unsigned int). This function will warn when the integer does not fit in four bytes:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> pack('I', 1000)
'\xe8\x03\x00\x00'
>>> pack('I', 10000000)
'\x80\x96\x98\x00'
>>> pack('I', 1000000000000000)
sys:1: DeprecationWarning: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
'\x00\x80\xc6\xa4'
```

You can also [specify endianness](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: This method is quite interesting. The only problem is that it still returns a string of a much higher (but at least constant) size.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing something here I think

when you send a character you will be sending 1 byte so even though

```
sys.getsizeof('\x05')
```

reports larger than 8 you are still only sending a single byte when you send it.  the extra overhead is python methods that are attached to EVERYTHING in python, those do not get transmitted

you complained about `getsizeof` for the struct pack answer but accepted the c_ushort answer so I figured I would show you this

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(struct.pack("I",15))
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(c_ushort(15))
80
```

however that said both of the answers should do exactly what you want

Comment: You are 100% correct. What you showed is exactly what I ran as well. Ideally I would like getsizeof to be 4, but because of what you mentioned that is practically impossible. But since, as you also said, what is sent is indeed of the correct size with both ctypes and struct.pack, I selected Naib 's answer just because it had a reference to both stuct.pack and ctypes, although @SimeonVisser 's answer was exactly what I was looking for. I hope it makes sense..

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if there's a better way to do this, but here's my naive approach:

```
def intn(n, num_bits=4):
    return min(2 ** num_bits - 1, n)
```

Comment: This caps the number at 2^n - 1, but it's infinitely more common for it to wrap around (so 2^n becomes 1).

Comment: @delnan That should be easy using `%` then.

Comment: @Thomas Yes. @sdasdadas Or `&`.