# How to create Python fixed length bits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bit-manipulation

I wish to do bitwise negation in Python.

My expectation:

```
negate(0001) => 1110
```

But Python's ~0b0001 returns -0b10. It seems Python truncate 1110 into -0b10.

How to keep the leading bits?

Moreover, why

```
bin(~0b1) yields -0b10?
```

How many bits are reserved for that datatype?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716315/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-unsigned-integer-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python uses arbitrary precision arithmetic, so you don't have to worry about the number of bits used. Also it returns `-0b10` for `bin(~0b1)`, because it understands that the result is `-2` and represents the number as it is `10` and keeps the sign in the front (only for the negative numbers).

But we can represent the number as we like using `format` function, like this

```
def negate(number, bits = 32):
    return format(~number & 2 ** bits - 1, "0{}b".format(bits))

print(negate(1))
# 11111111111111111111111111111110
print(negate(1, bits = 4))
# 1110
```

Or, as [suggested by eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285653/how-to-create-python-fixed-length-bits/23285826?noredirect=1#comment35653865_23285826),

```
def negate(number, bits = 32):
    return "{:0{}b}".format(~number & 2 ** bits - 1, bits)
```

Comment: @PahleviFikriAuliya That is actually not needed, earlier I used hardcoded `32` instead of `bits` in `2 ** bits`. Thats why I had to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Python acts as if its integers have infinitely many bits. As such, if you use `~` on one, the string representation can't start with an infinite number of `1`s, or generating the string would never terminate. Instead, Python chooses to represent it as a negative number as it would be using two's compliment. If you want to restrict the integer to a number of bits, `&` it against an appropriate mask:

```
>>> bin((~1) & 0b1111)
'0b1110'
```